# Proof positiveness condition CIR dynamic

Tags: interest-rates, stochastic-processes, models

Ciao All.
I'm studying the CIR model and this question came out.

Usually the Ornstein-Uhnlenbeck dynamic is used to build the CIR model:
let
$$
dX_t = aX_t + \sigma dW_t
$$ 
where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\sigma >0$. Then if we call $Y_t = X_t^2$ we get:
$$
dY_t = \left(\sigma^2 + 2aY_t \right) dt + 2 \sqrt{Y_t} \sigma dW_t
$$
which is a CIR dynamic.

**Starting from now we will use the usual notation:**

\begin{equation}
dY_t = a \left( b-Y_t \right)dt + \sigma \sqrt{Y_t} dW_t.
\end{equation}

Of course $Y_t$ is positive a.e. since it's equal to $X_t^2$.

My question is about the condition
$$
ab > 2 \sigma^2
$$

In fact according to many papers this is enough to make $Y_t$ positive.
Can you give a proof of this fact?

Thank you!
Ciao!

Comment: See [this paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1756450) for discussion.

Comment: @Gordon Thank you so much, very clear proof (but not so trivial as everybody says).